# How do I find the package name for an application that I want to uninstall?

Tags: apt

I tried

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove snipe2d
```

But I guess 'snipe2d' isn't the name of the game....so how do I find out what it is and how to put it into my terminal?

P.S. this is what it says when I put in the above code:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package snipe2d
```

EDIT: The official name of the game in question is: orbital eunuchs sniper

Comment: What's the name of the package that you installed?

Comment: orbital eunuchs sniper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you installed the game in the Software Center, you can just:

1. Go to the Software Center.
2. Search for it using terms similar to what it was called in the Software Center (which is often not the same as the actual package name).
3. Uninstall it in the Software Center.

You never even have to know what the  package is called.

<sup>(This seems to address [the actual goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in the question, though answers about searching packages would be good too.)</sup>

Comment: Yeah I did install it in Software Center...but i'm also new and I want to the hang of using the terminal. Thank You!

Comment: @CollinBlatt take a look at [Braim's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/404178/157741)... `apt-cache` is my favorite.

Answer (score 14):

1. Open the Software Center page for the application.
2. Scroll down to "Version".

   [image]
3. The package name is the part *before* the first space in the version.
   In your case, it is `orbital-eunuchs-sniper`.
4. You can then do whatever you want with it, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove orbital-eunuchs-sniper
   ```

---

Alternatively, if you know the path to a file which executes the application, you can also do

```
dpkg -S /path/to/file
```

This will print all packages which contain that file.

> Example:
>
> ```
> $ dpkg -S apt-get
> bash-completion: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/slapt-get
> apt: /usr/bin/apt-get
> apt: /usr/share/man/es/man8/apt-get.8.gz
> bash-completion: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-get
> apt: /usr/share/man/de/man8/apt-get.8.gz
> apt: /usr/share/man/pt/man8/apt-get.8.gz
> apt: /usr/share/man/pl/man8/apt-get.8.gz
> apt: /usr/share/man/fr/man8/apt-get.8.gz
> apt: /usr/share/man/man8/apt-get.8.gz
> apt: /usr/share/man/ja/man8/apt-get.8.gz
> ```

Answer (score 6):

I think you should have more luck using `apt-cache search`

```
apt-cache search snipe                 
esniper - simple, lightweight tool for sniping ebay auctions
orbital-eunuchs-sniper - anti-terrorist, pro-Eunuchs, satellite sniping game
orbital-eunuchs-sniper-data - game data files for the game Orbital Eunuchs Sniper
```

That will tell you all packages that has in it's description. Then you can do `sudo apt-get remove`:

```
sudo apt-get remove orbital-eunuchs-sniper orbital-eunuchs-sniper-data
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did not use Software Center, use

```
dpkg -S $(which snipe2d)
```

See also my blog on dpkg: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Dpkg

Comment: `which` is not required. Just `dpkg -S snipe2d` will work as well if you don't mind some more results.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `apt-file`, which keeps a database of all the files every package provides, then you can use `apt-file /path/to/snipe2d` to see which package provides that file, which you can then remove with `apt-get remove`

Comment: I think `dpkg -S /path/to/snipe2d` will be lot easier.