# Reporting specific Ubuntu Software Center issues?

Tags: software-center, openshot

To whom or where do I report issues with the Ubuntu Software Center?

I am trying to download OpenShot and it tells me that I have no Internet connection... Despite the fact that I do have a working Internet connection and I was able to install an unrelated program using the Ubuntu Software Center.

Clearly there is something wrong with this specific program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps to install the package:

1. [Get the package name](https://askubuntu.com/a/404179/176889).
2. Use this command in a terminal, replace `package` with the name from step 1.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install 'package'
   ```
3. The package should then be installed.

If these steps worked, it is a Software Center problem, you can report it via the steps in this question: [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/176889).

Comment: Champion, worked like a charm (that's a neat work-around, by the way)!

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it (Ask Ubuntu/Stack Exchange) said I had to wait wait five minutes... So I'm sucking on some cancer then I'll do it.